# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'online_chat.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, error-handling, circular-dependency

I have this error and I don't know where it comes from, I have read similar questions on stack-overflow but nothing since to work for me. Could you please tell me why I get this error?

[That's the full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kc4M.png)

`settings.py`

`ROOT_URLCONF = 'online_chat.urls'`

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
              path('secret-chamber/', admin.site.urls),
              path('', Index.as_view(), name='home_page'),

              path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='core/login.html'), name='log_in'),
              path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='log_out'),

              path('registration/', Registration.as_view(), name='registration'),
              path('contact-us/', ContactUs.as_view(), name='contact_us'),
              path('our-rules/', Rules.as_view(), name='our_rules'),

              path('user-page/', UserProfilePage.as_view(), name='user_page'),
              path('change-password/', ChangePassword.as_view(), name='change_password'),

              path('user-page/add-photos/', AddPhotos.as_view(), name='add_photos'),
              path('user-page/find-date/', FindDate.as_view(), name='find_date'),
              path('user-page/delete-image/<int:pk>/', DeletePhoto.as_view(), name='delete_photo'),
              path('user-page/edit/<int:id>/', EditUserProfile.as_view(), name='edit_page'),

              path('detail/<int:pk>/', ProfileSearch.as_view(), name='search_profile'),
              path('report/<int:pk>/', ReportMessage.as_view(), name='report'),

          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thank you for any help!

````
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── filters.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── my_style.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── media
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   │       ├── base.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── custom_filters.py
│   │   └── custom_tags.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── online_chat
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── routing.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt```
````

Comment: Please use the `tree` command to print the directory tree of your sources and add it to the question

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Thank you! I have added my tree

Comment: try remove  __pycache__ folder/.pyc files(some times help)

Comment: add some print/logs in the starting of online_chat/urls.py file, and examine.

Comment: @Jisson Thank you for reply!

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: @Jisson DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_filters',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'core',
    'channels',
    'chat',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'debug_toolbar',
    'rest_framework',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS